# Renaming part of file name with a node.js script

Tags: node.js, rename

I was wondering if it's possible to rename just part of a file name with a node.js script. I'm using node.js with fs. But I can only rename the whole thing.

```
1   const fs = require('fs');
  2 fs.readFile('./test.json', function(error, data) {
  3     if (error) {
  4         console.log(error);
  5         return;
  6     }
  7 
  8     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
  9     for(var p in obj) {
 10         fs.rename('./' + obj[p] + '.jpg', './' + p + '.jpg', function(err) {
 11             if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
 12         });
 13     }
 14 });
```

~

and this is my json file

```
1 {
  2         "DEC19" : "2019-12-08",
  3         "MAY19" : "2019-05-26"
  4 }
```

this json file contains only the part of the name that I want to change.

hope you can help me, and thanks (:

Comment: What error do you get with this code?

Comment: the error that I get is that it doesn't find the files. the full name of the files that I want to rename is 2019-12-08-a bunch of numbers.jpeg. I would like to change just the date part and leave the number as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you can rename the file while you are reading it within its callback. You may need to using `readFileSync`:

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      path = require('path');

let data = fs.readFileSync('./test.json');
let obj = JSON.parse(data);
let dir = 'scripts/';
for (var p in obj) {
  let search = RegExp(obj[p], 'g');
  let files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
  files.filter((file) => file.match(search))
       .forEach( (file) => {
    let filePath = path.join(dir, file)
    let newFile = path.join(dir, file.replace(search, p));
    fs.renameSync(filePath, newFile);
  });
}
```

Comment: It works to rename it but I'm trying to select just part of the name to be changed, that's what I don't know how

Comment: Does the files you need to change exists in the same directory?

Comment: yes, My idea was to move the files to the script directory everytime I would want to rename them

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please, check it out and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a json file, can you not read the file by requiring it and since it will be read as object, you could rename it after. Also consider using sync version if inside the for loop if it is a one time script.

something like

```
const obj = require("./test.json");

for(var p in obj) {
   fs.renameSync('./' + obj[p] + '.jpg', './' + p + '.jpg');
 }
```